# Time-adaptive compression tool

Tags: compression

I'm asking about a scenario of copying a big file to a remote server.

A simplest case is:

```
tar c myfile | ssh myserver tar x
```

If network connectivity is fast then all is fine.

On a slower network I do

```
tar c myfile | bzip2 -1 | ssh myserver tar xj
```

-- making my transfer faster at the cost of CPU time.

Of course I can play with compression ratio, typically trying to guess the right one so my CPU is not too busy and the network is saturated.

Is there a compression utility or a compression flag that would tell `bzip2`/`xz`/... to compress as much as possible while the output buffer is busy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
zstd --adapt
```

The [`zstd` compression utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zstandard) has an option that turns on adaptive compression (the option was added in `zstd` v1.3.6).  This would adjust the compression to "the current perceived I/O conditions".

See the `zstd` manual for more information.

A complete pipeline may look something like this:

```
tar -c -f - source_directory |
zstd --adapt |
ssh user@server 'cd /someplace && { zstd -d | tar -x -f -;}'
```

or

```
tar -c -f - source_directory |
zstd --adapt |
ssh user@server 'zstd -d | tar -x -C /someplace -f -'
```

If you add `-v` to the first `zstd` in the pipeline, you will get a progress indicator line saying something like

```
(L7) Buffered :  32 MB - Consumed : 192 MB - Compressed :  72 MB => 37.50%
```

where the `(L7)` indicates the compression level.  For any moderately large amount of data, you would expect it to fluctuate over time, showing that `zstd` is indeed adapting to the I/O conditions (and presumably also to the data itself).

Comment: Sadly, in ubuntu bionic repos there's currently `zstd 1.3.3`, which doesn't support the flag, but 1.4.0 I've built from sources does. Thank you.

Comment: @bohdan_trotsenko Thanks for the heads-up about that. I'll figure out when that option was added to the utility, and then I'll mention that in the answer too.

Comment: Combine with `-T0 --long` for the win.